# There are no email addresses or profiles when trying to configure a scheduled job to use email notification in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, scheduled-task

I have configured and tested the database mail. That all works.
I configured SQL Server agent to use the profile I created.
I restarted SQL Server agent.
When I configure the job and go to notifications and check email the drop down is still blank.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6):

Under SQL Server Agent, you need to go to the Operators category and add a new Operator (with an email address). You will then be able to select it in the notifications drop down.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, upvoted. But how do I connect the operator with a database email profile? After all, when creating / editing the operator, I can't enter an SMTP server and so on.

Comment: Under SQL Server Agent Properties/Alert system you have to enable and set Email profile which will be used to sent emails.